# Dynamic Distribution Groups through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: graph, dynamic

Has there been any changes on the Graph API with regards to the dynamic distribution group or is it still unsupported?
Tested with these but I couldn't retrieve any DDL.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

Comment: I am also looking the same. Any suggestions.

Comment: @Prakash got an answer in here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/376906/does-graph-api-support-dynamic-distribution-lists.html

Comment: Thanks @Russel. 

Hi Michev,

I have a couple of questions:
 1. When using powershell, will it require any additional permission on the APP? We are currently accessing customer tenants using the app?
 2. Can we use modern authentication to get Dynamic DL using that powershell command? 
 3. Also, found some otherway using EWS API service.ExpandGroup. It seems it only supports to get members of Dynamic DL but not to get list of Dynamic DL? Is this supported and recommended API for this type of work?
. 

Thanks
Prakash